# Understanding Object Orientation Multiple Periods

Tags: object, orientation

I have a Object Oritentation quesation.

I have created the following Pandas series:-

```
import pandas as pd

my_series1 = pd.Series(data = [200,201,202,203], index = ["London", "New York", "London", "Sydney"], name = "Test")
```

my_series1 is an object from the Class series (I think)

my_series1 has access to methods and properties, one example of this is checking if all the values in the series are unique using the code:-

`my_series1.is_unique`

I am happy with the above code.

This is where things get confusing, I can check if the index values are also unique using the code:-

`mmy_series1.index.is_unique`

The code above does not make sense to me, I don't fully understand how the is_unique property can be applied to the index column - I have been assuming that once an object has been created you can access a method by calling the object name followed by a "." and then the name of the function.

This idea of multiple periods is confusing me as i cannot connect the is_unique back to how the class is created.

Also would it be correct to say the following:-

1. An object has attributes
2. An object has methods

But are properties of an object??, are object properties and methods the same thing?

Can anyone help?

Thank you.